# jQuery.addClass() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue with `addClass()`. Somehow, it does not work with this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/0g1Lvk2j/20/

scroll to the end and close the last box by clicking on the orange box. The orange borders of the closed box should transfer to another visible box by removing the class `photo-src-as-main` from the closed box and adding it to the first visible box. However, it does not work!

```
    <div class="photo fn-photo-upload grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100" >
      <div class="photo-frame">
        <div class="photo-src fn-photo-upload-src">
          <div class="pu-btn-container"><span class="text-charcoal">/upload</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><div data-form="1" class="photo fn-photo-1 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="2" class="photo fn-photo-2 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="3" class="photo fn-photo-3 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 ">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="4" class="photo fn-photo-4 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 display-none">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="5" class="photo fn-photo-5 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100">
    <div class="photo-frame photo-src-as-main">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="6" class="photo fn-photo-6 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 display-none">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="7" class="photo fn-photo-7 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 display-none">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

### HTML:

```
    <div class="photo fn-photo-upload grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100" >
      <div class="photo-frame">
        <div class="photo-src fn-photo-upload-src">
          <div class="pu-btn-container"><span class="text-charcoal">/upload</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><div data-form="1" class="photo fn-photo-1 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="2" class="photo fn-photo-2 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="3" class="photo fn-photo-3 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 ">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="4" class="photo fn-photo-4 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 display-none">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="5" class="photo fn-photo-5 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100">
    <div class="photo-frame photo-src-as-main">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="6" class="photo fn-photo-6 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 display-none">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div><div data-form="7" class="photo fn-photo-7 grid-25 tablet-grid-50 mobile-grid-100 display-none">
    <div class="photo-frame">
      <div class="photo-src">
        <div class="photo-src-control">
          <div class="photo-src-remove "></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
    .display-none{
      display:none;
    }
    .photo-src-control{
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: orange;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    /*.photo-src-main{
        background: url('img/star.png') no-repeat center #c0c0c0;
    }
    .photo-src-main:hover{
        background-color: gold;
    }*/
    .photo-src-remove{
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .photo-src-remove:hover{
        background-color: red;
    }
     .photo .photo-src{

        /* border: 3px dashed #D2D2D2; */
        background-color: white;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url("img.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center 40%;
        position: relative;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.26);
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .photo-frame{
        width: 95%;
        margin: 5% auto;
        padding:3px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    .fn-photo-upload{
        background-image: url("img.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center 40%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .photo-loading .photo-src{
        background-image: url("imgLoader.gif")!important;
        background-position: center!important;
    }
    .photo-loading .photo-src-control{
        display: none;
    }
    .pu-btn-container{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 25%;
        width:100%;
    }
    .pu-btn-container span{
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .pu-form{
        width:0;
        height:0;
        border:0px solid #fff;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .photo-src-as-main{
        background: #DC7416;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.26);
    }
    /*.photo-src-as-main .photo-src-main{
        background-color: #DC7416;

    }*/
    .photo-src-as-main .photo-src{
        box-shadow:none!important;

    }
```

### javascript/jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".photo-src-remove").click(function(){
        var photo=$(this).parents().eq(3);
        var photoFrame=$(this).parents().eq(2);
        photo.addClass("display-none");

        if (photoFrame.hasClass("photo-src-as-main")) {
          //I dont understand why it refuses to add and remove this classname
          $(".photo").not(".fn-photo-upload,.display-none").find(".photo-frame").eq(0).addClass("photo-src-as-main")
          photoFrame.removeClass("photo-src-as-main");
        }
      })

      $(".photo-src").not(".fn-photo-upload-src").click(function(){
        $(".photo-frame").removeClass("photo-src-as-main")
        $(this).parent().addClass("photo-src-as-main")
      })


    })
```

Comment: @Pangloss Apart from semantics, Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion will take care of that. I don't see any issues caused by missing `;`.

Comment: Could it be that the element you are adding the class to currently has it's `display:none`? That's what it seems like here: https://jsfiddle.net/0g1Lvk2j/13/ I added `display:inline` to the class you are adding and the div appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that *both* your "click" handlers fire when you click on that orange square "photo-src-remove" element. Its parent is a "photo-src" element, so the click bubbles up to that. Thus, your code does add "photo-src-as-main" as you intend, but then the other click handler immediately removes it.

You can cancel event bubbling to fix that:

```
  $(".photo-src-remove").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();                   // <=== stop bubbling
    var photo=$(this).parents().eq(3);
    var photoFrame=$(this).parents().eq(2);
    photo.addClass("display-none");

    if (photoFrame.hasClass("photo-src-as-main")) {
      //I dont understand why it refuses to add and remove this classname
      $(".photo").not(".fn-photo-upload,.display-none").find(".photo-frame:first").addClass("photo-src-as-main")
      photoFrame.removeClass("photo-src-as-main");
    }
  })
```

I would strongly suggest that instead of navigating by nesting depth up the `.parents()` chain (eg, `.parents().eq(2)`), use `.closest()` to explicitly search by class name for the target parent. Using DOM structure is very fragile.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the right element, for sure. I try it like this and it work. Very ugly I know, but the problem is not the add/remove class, is the element returned on the selection.

```
 $(".photo-src").not(".fn-photo-upload-src").click(function(){
    $(".photo-frame").removeClass("photo-src-as-main")
    var frameList = $(".photo-frame").filter(':visible');
    $(frameList[frameList.length - 1]).addClass("photo-src-as-main")
  })
```